# Node/Babel : Switching from babel-node or babel-register to babel-cli for production

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Setup

Babel 6 (^6.0.0),
Node 5.4.0,
Express 4.13.x,

Both `babel-node` and `babel-register` have a warning to not be used in production on the
babel.io website. Basically transpiling on the fly like that is too slow for production.

So I've set things up to be transpiled with `babel-cli` and running pre-transpiled code.

The Problem:

During development, it's too slow re-transpile all the code and re-start the program for
every single change. I also can't see how a change monitor(e.g. nodemon) can be set for automatic reloads since we are now running the transpiled code and not the source(where changes are happening).

Question:

How do we set-up an easy way to switch between on-the-fly transpiling during development, and pre-transpiling for production?

Most examples I see `babel-node` and `babel-register` being used for development and production so I'm not sure what's a good strategy for quick development with babel while also preparing the code-base for production shipping.

Comment: "During development, it's too slow re-transpile" What makes you say that? You can set up a watcher to recompile the individual files that change and that would be almost instant. Your `nodemon` would still behave the same way, it'd just be watching the build output, rather than the original source files.

Comment: Well that's just it - I don't know how to watch the src code for changes, transpile(only what changed to be fast), and merge those changes with the build code. I imagine that process would need to happen before you could watch the build  for automatic reloads, but I'd even be happy just to have build code always ready to restart manually when a change is made and not have to wait for a complete transpiling of the src code in order to restart.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Actually trying to skip that long transpiling of all the src code is why I figured that switching between on-the-fly transpiling for dev and pre-transpiling for production was probably the solution, and shaped my question around that assumption. If there are quicker ways to transpile only what changed - let me know.

Comment: I assume you have read [the documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel) and tried the `--watch` option? Why are you not happy with that?

Comment: @FelixKling because ```--watch```, like it shows in the documentation, only watches a single file not the entire source code. I feel like these comments are being a little assumptive about the reality of this sticking point and hopefully doesn't trivialize the question to people who may potentially help. If watching the source code and transpiling the changes is how  it is done - then what are people using to watch and transpile changes?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Looking it the source code, it should work just fine. What else are people using? grunt, gulp, webpack or browserify I assume. The last two won't help though if you don't want to bundle the modules. But again, `babel --watch` should work. FWIW, lots of people seem to use it for their entire source code: https://github.com/search?q=Babel+--watch&type=Code&utf8=✓

Comment: Course I tried it! :) You could only imagine how ready I am to go back to coding and not trying to get Node.js work with the language it was built for. haha

Comment: @FelixKling - I added my npm scripts to the question. It wasn't updating the build folder though.

Comment: So I just setup a test on my machine with `babel src/ --out-dir dist --watch` and it is working as expected. Whenever I make a change to a file in `src` it recompiles the appropriate file. I even tried created a new file in `src` and it generated a new file in `dist`. How are you running the `watch-files` script?

Comment: I'm running "npm run build" and it calling the initial build, starting the server and calling watch.

Comment: Oh man... I don't know why I had my scripts running the server and setting watch. I'm running those scripts in separate shells and the transpiling is working beautifully. :) All the "watch-babel" libraries I was checking out on Github  made me miss the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out many highly popular Node boilerplate repositories on Github  are still using `babel-node` and `babel-register` for production code and that's probably because,not to long ago,they were much easier to use for setting up a fast reloading developing environment. **BUT, it's just as simple to use `babel-cli` and I recommend using it for both development and production code right out of the gate.**

With help from the comments, I got to my core question:

"When developing, how can I avoid the slow rebuilding of my source code when using `babel-cli`?"

Unlike the on-the-fly transpling that `babel-node` and `babel-register` offer, which is fast for restarting during changes in development, the `babel-cli` pre-transpiles your code to a build destination where your code can then be run separately in it's es5 format. During development, building code from source to build between each change is slow because you have to wait for every file to be transpiled before restarting your server.

**The solution is simple -all you need is babel-cli's `watch` method out-of-the-box can watch all your source code and quickly update your build code by only rebuilding files that updated while it watches.**

Sorry if the solution is painfully obvious as you read this but the babel docs only show code watching for single files and there currently there is a plethora of popular libraries on Github devoted specifically to watching entire folders for changes, and so I'm assuming the out-of-the-box solution is somewhat new, and makes using `babel-cli` an obvious choice over `babel-node` and `babel-register`.

So, all you have to do is use an npm script like so:

```
"watch-files" : "babel src --watch --out-dir build"
```

and restart your server in the build directory whenever an update is made(unless you set up an automatic reload that watches the build folder).

Credit to @FelixKling  and @aray12 comments that helped me see that `babel-cli` is really easy to use even during development.